# How to decompose any arbitrary unitary gate into just Rx and Ry rotation gates?

Tags: quantum-gate

I have the following exercise:

[image]

I tried to ask my university TA for some advice on how I could solve such questions and he literally just told me that I should try a bunch of combinations of rx and ry gates. Basically, try to solve such questions by trial and error.

This just doesn't make sense to me, is there no actual kind of algorithm/procedure to deconstruct gates into a given set of other gates?

Comment: For single-qubit gates, you can use Euler decomposition. For $n>2$ qubits you can look into KAK decomposition https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0507171. Appendix B of this paper might also help https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove to yourself that

$$ RZ(\theta) = RX(\pi/2)RY(\theta)RX(-\pi/2) $$

where $
 RX(\theta) = 
            \begin{pmatrix}
                \cos{\theta/2}   & -i\sin{\theta/2} \\
                -i\sin{\theta/2} & \cos{\theta/2}
            \end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \  RY(\theta) = 
            \begin{pmatrix}
                \cos{\theta/2}   & -\sin{\theta/2} \\
                \sin{\theta/2} & \cos{\theta/2}
            \end{pmatrix}$

and $  RZ(\theta/2) = 
            \begin{pmatrix}
                e^{-i\theta/2} & 0 \\
                0 & e^{i\theta/2}
            \end{pmatrix}$

Therefore,

$$ RZ(\pi/3) = RX(\pi/2)RY(\pi/3)RX(-\pi/2) $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after doing the math I can see that this works. 
But where did you find this RZ(θ)=RX(π/2)RY(θ)RX(−π/2) relation? 

Is it like some kind of common formula that everyone should know?

Comment: It's something that people try to remember but the idea is essentially from DaftWullie's answer. Note that $RX(\pi/2) = \sqrt{X}$ and $RX(-\pi/2) = \sqrt{X}^{\dagger} $.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to use the Euler decomposition to split any arbitrary single-qubit rotation into 3 steps about two different, perpendicular axes.

However, in this case, there's a trick. If you have a sequence such as
$$
\sqrt{Y}I\sqrt{Y}^\dagger=I\qquad \sqrt{Y}X\sqrt{Y}^\dagger=iYX=Z,
$$
then you can reasonably easily find an $\alpha$ such that
$$
\sqrt{Y}R_X(\alpha)\sqrt{Y}^\dagger
$$
gives you the evolution you want.